# Intellij Idea hides my spring cloud contracts under test/resources

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, spring-cloud-contract

I have written my first spring-cloud-contract using Intellij Idea 2018.2. Everything works fine, but I cannot edit the contract from within Idea because it hides the complete src/test/resources/contracts folder in the project view. So I have to individually open each contract vi the file -> open... menu.

Can anybody tell me how I can access my contract files in Idea from the project view?

Comment: Isn't it marked as a excluded folder? Do you have "Show excluded" option enabled in project tree?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled that option. I can see all other files and folders under src/test/resources. Only the contracts folder is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with maven. It enough to refresh the project and the folder will be added to the classpath